# Numeric range: present or not

Tags: functions

There is a formula to test whether a number is included in a range? For example, if 3 is between -2 and 6.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE!
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: The key here is to understand what we mean by the range. Do you include all Real numbers between the range ? Only integers ? A start would be to have the list as a Range and use MemberQ

Comment: There are **[things to do after your question is answered](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)**. Its a good idea to stay vigilant for some time, better approaches may come later improving over previous replies. Experienced users may point alternatives, caveats or limitations. New users should **test answers before [voting](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote)** and **wait 24 hours before [accepting](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer)** the best one. Participation is essential for the site, please come back to do your part tomorrow.

Comment: As you receive **give back**, vote and answer questions, keep the site useful, be kind, correct mistakes and share what you have learned.
Why not choosing a meaningful username?

Answer (score 8):

### *Mathematica 10.3*

In *Mathematica 10.3* there is a new function [`Between`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Between.html):

```
Between[3, {2, 5}]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

### Previous versions of *Mathematica*

You can define your own function with the same behavior:

My take

```
mybetween[a_, {b_, c_}] := TrueQ[b <= a <= c]
```

or as suggested by @mmal

```
mybetween[a_, {b_, c_}] := IntervalMemberQ[Interval[{b, c}], a]
```

We can test it:

```
mybetween[6, {2, 5}]
```

> ```
> False
> ```

```
mybetween[3, {-2, 6}]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Comment: Change `<` to `≤` in `myBetween` to get the same behavior as the new built-in function.

Comment: @shrx Done, thanks for checking this.

Answer (score 8):

```
IntervalMemberQ[Interval[{-2, 6}], 3]
(* => True *)
```

Answer (score 4):

Have a look [Range](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Range.html) and [MemberQ](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MemberQ.html). As well [Testing Expressions](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/TestingExpressions.html).

```
myList = Range[-2, 6, 1]
```

> {-2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}

```
myVal = 3
```

> 3

```
MemberQ[myList, myVal]
```

> True

Comment: Only works for integers though...

Comment: could be what he meant though..

Answer (score 2):

You can visualize membership with

```
NumberLinePlot[{-2 <= x < 1 || x > 3, x == -1}, x]
```

[image]